# Sending large messages from server to client with pollingDuplexHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, silverlight, pollingduplexhttpbinding

First, I'd like to ask for the theory, because I didn't find any related documentation: We have a Silverlight client and a WCF service. The communication between them is through a pollingDuplexHttpBinding.
Suppose the server wants to sent to the client a message which its size is larger than the set MaxBufferSize and MaxReceivedMessageSize. What is going behind the scenes in that case?

Now, here is my actual experience with this issue:
The binding configuration on the server-side:

```
<binding name="eventServiceBinding" sendTimeout="00:00:10" inactivityTimeout="24:00:00" receiveTimeout="24:00:00" serverPollTimeout = "00:01:00"/>
```

Send a large (i.e. larger than the value set in client's binding's properties as described above) message from the server to the client. Then, send a second (not large) message => I got a send timeout for the second message (I don't know if the client ever got the first message).
I've tried to search for some helpful logging in order to see what happens with the first message. Done it both in the server side (by activating the WCF logger) and on the client side (by using Fidler). I've found nothing really interesting in the log (but maybe I didn't search in the correct places).

Moreover - when sendTimeout is set to large value (say 10 minutes), it looks like all additional messages sent from server to client are "stuck" - never received by the client and no exceptions are thrown until the send timeout is reached. In addition, I experience  a strange phenomenon in which no communication between any client and any service exposed by the hosting IIS application is working - until I reset IIS. I am not 100% sure though that this is related to the previous problem described here.

Setting the MaxBufferSize and MaxReceivedMessageSize properties in the client side's binding seems to resolve both issues.

Please let me know if you have any experience with such issue and whether you can tell what's actually is going behind the scenes  within WCF here.